# Change a javascript Filter List to display in a HTML drop down

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to add a HTML filter as shown in link below. I have the filter replicated from the link, but I want to modify the javascript to display in a drop down vs as a UL element: http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_demo_create_class_filter.htm.

```
<label for="solutions-filter">Topics</label><select id="solutions-filter" name="solutions-filter">
          <option value="all">
            All
          </option>
          <option value="acct_overview">
            Account Overview
          </option>
          <option value="active_view">
            Account Overview
          </option>
    </select>
```

I have bold'ed the two lines from the javascript code below that I believe I need to change to make it fit into this model, but I'm at a loss on how to change it being new to JavaScript. Does anyone have time to take a peak and see what I may need to change to add the filter into this type of drop down?

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

    // map the classes for each item into a new array
    classes = $("#demo-list li a").map(function(){
        return $(this).attr("class").split(' ');
    });

     // create list of distinct items only
     var classList = distinctList(classes);

     // generate the list of filter links
     **var tagList = '<ul id="tag-list"></ul>';**
     tagItem = '<li><a href="#" class="active">all</a></li>';
     $.each(classList, function(index,value){
         var value = value.replace("-", " ");
        tagItem += '<li><a href="#">'+value+'</a></li>';
    });

    // add the filter links before the list of items
    **$("#demo-list").before($(tagList).append(tagItem));**

    // filter the demo list when the filter links are clicked
    $('#tag-list li a').live('click',function(e){

        var getText = $(this).text().replace(" ", "-");
        if(getText == 'all'){
            $("#demo-list li a").slideDown();
        } else {
            $("#demo-list li a").fadeOut();
            $("#demo-list li a."+getText).fadeIn();
        }

        // add class "active" to current filter item
        $('#tag-list li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // prevent the page scrolling to the top of the screen
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
// Function to create a distinct list from array
function distinctList(inputArray){
    var i;
    var length = inputArray.length;
    var outputArray = [];
    var temp = {};
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        temp[inputArray[i]] = 0;
    }
    for (i in temp) {
        outputArray.push(i);
    }
    return outputArray;
}
</script>
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I implemented this solution, and it worked steller. 

In addition to this, how would we change the javascript to add a query string. I would like to be able to send out a link to my page with a pre-sort. Example, I want all "X" and share the link users. 

How would I modify, I haven't been able to figure it out.